# Inserting multiple pictures with space for captions in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, format, pictures

I'm doing weekly lab reports for school and have a lot of screen shots (JPEG) that I need to insert into the reports.

If I click on Insert Picture and select all the files at once it will insert them into the report but with no space between them for me to write my little blurb about that section of the lab.  They are also far too big and need to be reduced to about 40% of their size but that's another issue.

How can I insert all my pictures at once whilst still giving me some space between each one to write and/or add a caption?

Comment: Gaff, I find it rude that you would edit my question - not for the sake of clarity but for stylistic format - and provide nothing helpful to the problem I'm asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Insert the images.
2. Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything.
3. Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Find and Replace dialog.
4. In the `Find what` textbox type `^g` to search for graphics.
5. In the `Replace with` textbox type `^&^p^p` to insert the image that was found along with two paragraph marks (the first one will be used to separate each image from the next, the second one will be used for the label).
6. Click `Replace All`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the text spacing option `In line with text`, and then press enter a few times after the picture. this will create some space for writing blurbs.

Or, if that isn't what you want, try one of these options:

[image]

Here is an article that [helps you](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Wrap-text-around-pictures-in-Word-bdbbe1fe-c089-4b5c-b85c-43997da64a12) wrap text around pictures.